# Showing a popup window from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, placeholder, android-popupwindow

I want to show a popup window from my PlaceHodler class extending Fragment when the button is clicked. For a test, I wrote this code which really works, but I guess it's ridiculous (using Button object as a parent view and so on... I couldn't find another way to make it work...). Please look at this code and advice me how to improve it. Please don't judge me because I'm a very beginner in programming.

My code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        final Button button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("ilog", "onClick() works");
                PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
                TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                LayoutParams linearparams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tv.setLayoutParams(linearparams1);
                tv.setText("Testing");
                pw.setContentView(tv);
                pw.setWidth(400);
                pw.setHeight(180);
                pw.showAtLocation(button1, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 25, 25);
                pw.update();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that your button doesn't have to be final.  You can just use "view" as that's being passed into your onClick() method.  That said, you can make this work with anything that you can assign an OnClickListener too.  As an experiment I used your code with a TextView.  Works perfectly, however, thoughts on dismissing the window?

Answer (score 6):

popwindow in fragment and activity almost the same except they way you get contrext , in activity this , fragment getActivity()

here is the code to create popWindow

```
    View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

// define your view here that found in popup_layout 
// for example let consider you have a button 

Button btn = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button);

// finally show up your popwindow
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);
```

reference [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)